# ReactJS - How to accept HTML attribute data-*, aria-*?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a litte problem while creating a dropdown menu with bootstrap, in document https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html has said **React supports all data-* and aria-* attributes as well as every attribute in the following lists, all attributes are camel-cased..**.

EX:

```
React.DOM.div(
   {
      className: 'dropdown', // available
      dataToggle: 'dropdown', // not available
      ariaExpanded: true // not available
   }
)
```

when run, attribute data-* and aria-* same not available?? i don't know why so???What could I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: just use normally as

```
data-toggle: 'dropdown'
```

According to React Docs:

> All DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers) should be camelCased to be consistent with standard JavaScript style. We intentionally break with the spec here since the spec is inconsistent. However, data-* and aria-* attributes conform to the specs and should be lower-cased only.

You can look it at [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-differences.html)

I've added a quick JSFiddle that make use of data attributes with JSX. I know it was quite messy (it was the best I come up with shorted amount of time).But you can see the use of data attribute with react in action.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it as follows:

```
React.DOM.div(
{
  className: 'dropdown',
  'data-toggle': 'dropdown',
  'aria-expanded': true
})
```